# asp.net core favicon.ico goes through custom middleware

Tags: asp.net-core, favicon, asp.net-core-middleware

In my CustomMiddleware, I have a simple logging and some Authenticated user related code.

It seems like favicon.ico request goes through CustomMiddleware, but request path is "/" same as index page page. can not differentiate.
If I open up a link like this - https://localhost:5001/favicon.ico, it does not hit my debug point.

**I need help to understand why first time ONLY request "/", it goes through CustomMiddleware ???**

[image]

In the CustomMiddleware, first two request path "/" (one is Index), IsAuthenticated is false.
after that, it is always true as it goes through OIDC authentication.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The order of the Middlewares is very important and they run from top to bottom They can receive the request, process it, and pass that request to the next Middleware, or not. When the file request like `https://localhost:5001/favicon.ico` reaches the `UseStaticFile`  Middleware, it processes that request and no longer sends it to its lower Middleware
But when the request is not a file request like `https://localhost:5001/`, the `UseStaticFile`  Middleware receives the request and passes it to the next middleware.
This is why the request does not reach your custom `Middleware`. If you want it to be called, you must register your Middleware before the `UseStaticFile` Middleware  like this :

```
app.UseMiddleware<CustomMiddlware>();

app.UseStaticFiles();
```

**You only need to pay attention to one point: static files like css and ... are cached by the browser after first request. If you request them again, your request will not reach your APP and will be processed by the browser**.

Comment: Thanks Mohammad. 

I do understand the middleware order importance. But unfortunately favicon request seems to o hit the custom middleware, which it shouldn’t be. It should be served by staticfiles middleware. There is problem. I do believe I might be doing something wrong in cookie configuration.

Comment: this is the new issue that you raised is that the request for favicon ‌ reaches your custom middlelover, so how did you find out?

Answer (score 1):

You could read the offcial document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0

The ASP.NET Core request pipeline consists of a sequence of request delegates, called one after the other.

Each delegate can perform operations before and after the next delegate. Exception-handling delegates should be called early in the pipeline, so they can catch exceptions that occur in later stages of the pipeline.

When a delegate doesn't pass a request to the next delegate, it's called short-circuiting the request pipeline. Short-circuiting is often desirable because it avoids unnecessary work. For example, Static File Middleware can act as a terminal middleware by processing a request for a static file and short-circuiting the rest of the pipeline.

You could write two custommiddle and understand how middlewareworks

```
public class MyCustomMiddleWare
    {
        private RequestDelegate _next;
        public MyCustomMiddleWare(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }
        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            var pathstring = context.Request.Path.ToString();
            var pathlist = pathstring.Split("/").ToList();
            if (pathlist[1]=="")
            {
                await _next.Invoke(context);
            }
            else
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Result");
            }            
        }
    }

    public class MyAnotherCustomMiddleWare
    {
        private RequestDelegate _next;
        public MyAnotherCustomMiddleWare(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }
        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }
    }
```

in startupclass:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
   {
      .......
     app.UseStaticFiles();
     app.UseMiddleware<MyCustomMiddleWare>();
     app.UseMiddleware<MyAnotherCustomMiddleWare>();
     .......
   }
```

Test Result:

[image]
[image]

If you open up a link of staticfile and the request hit your custommiddleware behind UseStaticFile Middleware,check if the static file exists.
(Has the BuildAction property of file set as "content"?and check the codes in csproj related which update content files)

[image]